# How to enable scrolling on nested ListView in Nativescript?

Tags: android, typescript, listview, nativescript

**ListView** scroll is working fine when only one **ListView** is there. If i create a nested ListView and try to scroll only parent **ListView** is scrolling. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

```
<ListView [items]="items">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <GridLayout class="list-view" rows="auto, *">
            <StackLayout row="0" class="list-view__content" (tap)="toggleAccordion(item)">
                <GridLayout columns="*, auto">
                    <FlexboxLayout col="0" alignItems="center">
                        <Label class="list-view__content__headline" [class.has-selected]="item.count > 0" textWrap="true" [text]="item.title"></Label>
                        <Label class="list-view__content__count" textWrap="true" *ngIf="item.count > 0" [text]="item.count"></Label>
                    </FlexboxLayout>
                    <StackLayout col="1">
                        <Image *ngIf="item.opened" src="font://&#xf077;" class="fas" width="15"></Image>
                        <Image *ngIf="!item.opened" src="font://&#xf078;" class="fas" width="15"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout row="1" *ngIf="item.values && item.values.length > 0 && item.opened">
                <ns-multi-select-search [data]="item (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"></ns-multi-select-search>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

`ns-multi-select-search` component having nested ListView

```
<GridLayout rows="auto, 140" class="select">
    <StackLayout row="0">
        <SearchBar hint="Search here ..." (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)" (clear)="onClear($event)" (loaded)="onSearchBarLoaded($event)"></SearchBar>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout row="1" class="select__content" *ngIf="(allItems && allItems.length > 0)">
        <ListView [items]="allItems">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                <GridLayout columns="*, auto" (tap)="toggleSelected(item)" class="select__content__list">
                    <StackLayout col="0">
                        <Label class="select__content__list__label" [text]="item.name" textWrap="true"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout col="1">
                        <Image *ngIf="item.checked" src="~/assets/images/checked-check-box.png" width="20" class="m-t-5"></Image>
                        <Image *ngIf="!item.checked" src="~/assets/images/default-check-box.png" width="20" class="m-t-5"></Image>
                    </StackLayout>
                </GridLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
    <FlexboxLayout row="1" *ngIf="(allItems && allItems.length === 0)" flexDirection="column" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" class="select__content flex-error">
        <Label class="message" text="No match found!"></Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Just an idea: Nativescript documentation mentions that if you nest a listview in a scrollview or the other way around, then the nested one should specify a height. Maybe that also applies for nesting a listview in a listview, so you could try with specifying a height. https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/listview

Comment: @francisduvivier Thanks for the suggestion but I have already tried this, it renders but nested view **(child listview/scrollview with height)** is not scrollable & this is my problem, only parent is scrolling on scroll up or scroll down not child.

Comment: Hmm, what you could do for further debugging, is using the Android layout inspector in Android Studio to find out exactly which native views are being used and with properties. It would also be useful to add a dump or screenshot of that to the question.